# Couldn't find Spree::Page Error how to solve this Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have integrated spree static pages gem in my existing spree app.And I created one new page in admin side but the page link is displayed this following error.

Couldn't find Spree::Page
Couldn't find Spree::Page with [WHERE "spree_pages"."visible" = $1 AND (spree_pages_stores.store_id = 1) AND "spree_pages"."slug" = $2]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Just noticed it seems to be unchecking my store check box on every save in admin side.